# Where to set java compiler options in VSCode

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

I hava a Java project that uses reflection tech while collecting class method info like method name, return type, parameters info of the method of some classes. In order to get the real parameter name defined for method other than just get "arg*", I should compile classes with -parameters option.

I have been finding solutions for half a day, unfortunatly still can't find where to set the compiler options in vscode.

Both Eclipse and Idea provide a way to set compiler options with "-parameters", in eclipse there is a option in "Java-> Compiler" configurations, which is "Store information about method parameters(usable via reflection)", and in Idea there is a input to add option "-parameters" manually.

[image: Add -parameters compiler option in Eclipse]

[image: Add -parameters compiler option in Idea]

Comment: All compilation is done by Tasks so look in `tasks.json`

Comment: @rioV8 Thanks, but I can't find tasks.json file, I have the newest version 1.50.1 vscode installed.

Comment: @rioV8 I create a new tasks.json file from template, I'll try it later, thanks.

Comment: use **Terminal** | **Configure Tasks** to create a task.json

Comment: @rioV8 Thanks:) I am still trying to figure it out how to config compilation option via tasks.json.

Comment: read the Tasks doc on how to add args to the compile command